# MongoDB one-to-few where few needs to be unique

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently designing something in MongoDB and I wonder what the best pattern is for a one to few relationship.

My user document structure is a follows:

```
{
    "email": "some@email.com",
    "gender": "M",
    "name": "Some Name",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "timezone": "UTC +8",
    "country": "China",
    "accounts":[ 
       {
            "platform_id" : NumberLong(1),
            "id" : "556as1234432bb"
       },
       {
            "platform_id" : NumberLong(2),
            "id" : "82378437BA98"
       },
    ],
}
```

My question is for the accounts part. There will only be very few per user, so it seems a perfect candidate for embedding. Also, 5% of the cases I will need to use these ID's to retrieve the entire object, from that point forward I can use the _id field.

But:

1. I need to make sure that the platform+id is unique across all users
2. When adding I need to make that a user has only one ID per platform_id

Question:
I currently do not understand the combination of indexes and queries that would help me achieve this. How do I best model this?

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description of your requirement,as a solution to it you need to create an unique compound index

Just refer the example as mentioned below

```
db.user.createIndex({ "accounts.platform_id": 1, "accounts.id": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

For more detailed description regarding unique compound index please refer the documentation as mentioned in following URL

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Comment: Will this make it unique across the entire collection? And how do I ensure part 2 of the question?

Comment: @JeroendeLau Unique Index will create a unique combination of indexed fields across entire collection

Comment: @JeroendeLau  This answer does not solve the second requirement. However, this should be handled on the application side. Put the logic where it belongs to. ;)

Comment: I've tried using this method but it doesn't appear to work. If I create the index as described I get a duplicate key error if I create different keys. I think the problem is that the key is not looking in the Array of accounts, but looking at account.platform_id, accounts.id directly, which does not exist.

E11000 duplicate key error index: account.users.$accounts.platform_id_1_accounts.id_1 dup key: { : null, : null }